# Reload system config to get last saved values in magento 2

Tags: magento2

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->reinit();
```

This method invalidates the config cache and performs a complete reload of the configurations in magento 1.x

How can i do this for magento 2.x

I want to invalidate cache because my custom options not show latest results after save configurations, But need to refresh or flush cache.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `vendor/magento/module-analytics/Cron/SignUp.php`

```
    /**
     * Reinitable Config Model.
     *
     * @var ReinitableConfigInterface
     */
    private $reinitableConfig;
    ......

    $this->reinitableConfig->reinit();
```

We can use `Magento\Framework\App\ReinitableConfig` - `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ReinitableConfigInterface`